# Php caching and possible generation of static files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

Im running a website through the basics of a wordpress setup.

For some reason the pages/files are being cached somewhere. I haven't been able to find any static file generation but for example when i log out from a user it doesn't regonize that all cookies has been destroyed.

Also updating stylesheet and the core .php files may take a few refresh before appearing on the site.

I'v tried to set up filematch in the .Htaccess with an expiration date before the present (i had it to 1998).

Also tried inline php at the first line of my .php files to setup headers with nocache information.

None of the above has worked.

Any suggestions or clues would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the headers in the chrome/firefox web dev tools.

Comment: Thank you! I have gone through my source code and it seems that some jquery code is creating a class on <html> tag called applicationcache. I'm not into Jquery but can this be the reason? If so is this something new included in the standard jquery files?

Comment: That doesn't seem related. I meant look at the network log and see what the browser thinks the cache timeouts are for the individual files.

Comment: As i can see everything is setup to my likings. Images, css and js all got an expiration date and is set to be cached. The main domain has: `no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0` and the page itself is also listed with: `no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`

Answer (score 0):

Also updating stylesheet and the core .php files may take a few refresh before appearing on the site.

For that when you do any change in CSS/stylesheet/JS file then after stylesheet file string pass version number like below

Before

https://stackoverflow.com/style.css?v=1.2

After

https://stackoverflow.com/style.css?v=1.3

So page caching issue is resolved.